# display tomcat localhost page using hosts file in windows

Tags: tomcat, localhost, tomcat8, hosts, hosts-file

I have setup tomcat with an application deployed to ROOT location. entering localhost or 127.0.0.1 shows the application front page.

After that I modified the windows hosts file like this:

127.0.0.1  [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

Now when I hit [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) it throws 404 error instead of the localhost page. Any idea how to route it to localhost instead?

Comment: 404 might mean tomcat didn't find the requested page BUT the answer comes from localhost anyway.

Comment: That is not the right understanding of the problem.

If I type "127.0.0.1" in the browser it takes me to tomcat application correctly.
But if I type "www.google.com" its not taking me to tomcat application. This is despite me setting up hosts file to take it to localhost instead of www.google.com

Comment: But that's not a tomcat issue but rather a DNS/OS configuration issue. I would suggest using something like `fake.example.com` instead.